# Running Local Java Application with File System & Port restrictions

Tags: java, security

I need to run a java application (not an applet or JNLP, but a full blown application in the JRE) and need some restrictions on:

1. File System - The app could only access 1 folder to read & write (this would be a fixed path for the app's reference like / )
2. Ports - The app could only access several local ports. (eg could only access port 8080 / 3306 only)

Is there a way to do this? I have searched through Java Security & Policies but came nothing close to a solution.

I am considering to write a container to run this app or changing / overriding the classes (in case of OpenJDK). Is this ok?

This is for an open source project that we are about to start, Appreciate some good advice from the wise StackExchange community.

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and most basic, run the java application with a user who has the minimum permissions required for the app to do its work.

Secondly, set the java `SecurityManager` and configure it.

Comment: Thx for you answer, The idea is to force the app to only read & write 1 folder, so its very secure as any users folders eg documents are not accessible by this app. Kinda a Jailed App.

Answer (score 1):

[SJuan76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598289/sjuan76) has the right answer here. The **SecurityManager** is the appropriate way to restrict files/directories a java app can access. [This tutorial](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.security/CustSecurityMgr.html) might be a good guide to setting that up.

You can restrict the ports your java app listens on. But restricting ports really requires an OS level firewall to be configured.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I find Security Manager flaky for this type of application that we are doing (I should have detailed this earlier)

Comment: I suppose meddling with the Classloaders should be an option for the port restriction?